# How does the strength of magnetic field at the center of current carrying circular coil depends on the radius, number of turns and current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How and why does the strength of magnetic field at center of current carrying circular coil depend on the radius $r$, number of turns $N$ and the current flowing in the coil $I$.
I know that $B \propto \frac{1}{r}$, $B\propto N$ and $B \propto I$.

Comment: This is something which is very easy to look up using a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Ampère's circuital law states that the line integral of the magnetic field around some closed curve $C$ is equal to the enclosed current $I_{enc}$ :

$$\oint_c\vec{B} \cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0I_{enc}$$

By solving the integral you should be able to obtain the relationships that you are looking for

Comment: Ampere's law can give a reasonable answer if applied near the center of a long coil.  Use a rectangular loop.  On side of the loop on the axis inside, one on the outside, and the two connected by ends perpendicular to the axis. Assume the field is zero outside, and uniform and parallel to the axis inside.

Comment: Yes you are right. However, since a number of "N" turns around the coil was mentioned I assumed we were talking about a solenoid

Answer (score -1):

Using Ampere's circuital law for a single loop of the solenoid, we have
$$B*L=(\mu)(i)$$
where:

- L is the length of the solenoid.
- $\mu$ is the (permeability of free space)
- i is the enclosed current

This implies that if there are N windings in the solenoid, $$ B=(\mu)(N)(i)/L$$

Comment: Thanks.. Dude..  So B=(μ)(N/L)(i)    =>B=(μ)(n)(I)

Comment: This answer is wrong. You are saying that the solution of a single looped wire can be expressed as $B = \frac {\mu N I}{L} $. In order to determine the solution of a single looped wire you have to use Biot-Savarts law. $\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int_c \frac{ I d\vec{l} \times \vec{r}'}{|\vec{r}'|^3  }$.

Comment: It does appear that Mr. Walavalker is looking for the field at the center of a thin coil rather than a long solenoid.